# VB.NET GroupBy multiple number of properties

Tags: vb.net, linq

Currently, I've got the following code which groups 'items' which is a List(Of CLass1) based on multiple properties (prop1 & prop2).

```
Dim matchedMethods  = items.GroupBy(Function(x) New With_
               {Key x.prop1, Key x.prop2, Key x.prop3}).ToList()
```

This works okay for grouping known number of properties but what if I want it sorted by 'n number of properties' (prop1 and then prop2 and then prop3 and then propN...).

Comment: You said *"**group**ing known number of properties but what if I want it **sort**ed"* - with this whole question, are you asking about grouping or sorting?

Comment: Grouping. Items with same prop1=x, 2=y, 3=z should be grouped together, items with prop1=x1, prop2=y2, prop3=z2 grouped together, etc. if this makes sense

Comment: AFAIK that's how it works already: When LINQ does a grouping for you, you specify a key, and out of it you get a sequence of IGroupings which is kinda like a `Dictionary(Of keyType, List(Of inputValueType))`; each IGrouping has a Key and itself is a list of the grouped values. If you had 5 Person instances, three called John who are 27 and two called Paul age 38. and you GroupBy name and age you get 2 IGroupings, one has a Key of John,27 and has 3 Person objects (all are John,27) and the other IGrouping has a key of Paul,38 and is an enumerable of two Person who are both Paul and 38

Comment: I'm trying to let the user select the GroupBy, so rather than being just 'name' and 'age' it could be, say 'dob' or more. My question (apologies if it wasn't clear from earlier) is how do I use a varying number of groupings. So, rather than explicitly passing 3 properties like I have done in my code above, how can I pass n number of properties. The user might want to group by just prop1 or prop1,2,3,4,5 or prop3,2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the System.Linq.Dynamic library to achieve this: it allows you to pass expressions in strings (and hence you can build the strings dynamically).

I believe your code, in SDL, would be:

```
Dim keySelector = "new(it.prop1, it.prop2, it.prop3)"
items.GroupBy(keySelector, "it").ToList()
```

(but I'm not in a position to test it at the moment)

To vary it build the string differently:

```
Dim keySelector = "new("
If GroupByProp1CheckBox.Checked Then keySelector &= "it.prop1,"
If GroupByProp2CheckBox.Checked Then keySelector &= "it.prop2,"
...
keySelector = keySelector.TrimEnd(","c) & ")"
```

"it" is a predefined thing in Dynamic.Linq; the equivalent of `x` in `Function(x)` i.e. the list item

You'll need to add System.Dynamic.Linq.Core via nuget. There is also an older System.Dynamic.Linq library that, in my experience, is easier to get working with certain project types (e.g. .net framework windows forms)

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up doing it like this, basically use if statement to select the properties based on the number of propN-->  return the prop if there is one, else just return nothing.

Works like I want it to (@Calius Jard), will have to come back to the Dynamic Library at some point (thanks for that btw) when I get some time.
The only bit that I'm not quite satisfied my method is the Key is exported as {v0=prop1,  v1=prop2, vN=propN} and not as a list or dict. So, I ended up using some string manipulation to read these keys.

```
   matchedRecords = items.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {Key .v0 = CallByName(x, prop(0).ToString, CallType.Get),
                                                      Key .v1 = If(prop.Count >= 2, CallByName(x, prop(1).ToString, CallType.Get), Nothing),  
                                                      Key .v2 = If(prop.Count >= 3, CallByName(x, prop(2).ToString, CallType.Get), Nothing),
                                                      Key .v3 = If(prop.Count >= 4, CallByName(x, prop(3).ToString, CallType.Get), Nothing),
                                                      Key .v4 = If(prop.Count >= 5, CallByName(x, prop(4).ToString, CallType.Get), Nothing),
                                                      Key .v5 = If(prop.Count >= 6, CallByName(x, prop(5).ToString, CallType.Get), Nothing)}).ToList
```